# Memory issue with mongoose aggregate even with allowDiskUsage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, out-of-memory

I am trying to run a big query on a mongodb db, that will, knowingly, use a lot of memory. i am encountering a constant memory error when exceeding the 100mb usage :

```
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Used too much memory for a single array. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes. The array contains 170732 elements and is of size 104857566 bytes. The element being added has size 609 bytes
```

setting the `allowDiskUsage` to true, didn't change anything. i am using this plugin : https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 to conduct the aggregate. it just adds some easy pagination features.

i also tried to set the `allowDiskUseByDefault` to true on the server shell with

```
db.adminCommand(
    {
        setParameter: 1,
        allowDiskUseByDefault: true
    }
)
```

and it says that it was already set to true, which according to the docs should make the disk usage the default choice, but right now it is not doing anything.

the aggregate pipline i am using has only 2 stages, match and lookup and i expect it to use a lot of memory

here is my query :

```
const ItemAggregate = Item.aggregate()
        ItemAggregate.allowDiskUse(true) // this doesn't work
        ItemAggregate.match(filters) // filters is an empty object for now

        ItemAggregate.lookup({
            from: Price.collection.name,
            localField: "product_id",
            foreignField: "product_id",
            as: "prices",
        })
```

Note : i am running the mongoDb community on y local machine

Comment: Perhaps if you show your query and describe what you are trying to do, a less memory intensive query could be suggested.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i am not trying to debug that really. and my query has only 2 stages, match and lookup based on one field, it's really super basic already, i mean there is nothign to optamize, i'll paste an example

Comment: Is `"product_id"` in either collection an array?  It's difficult to see with the query shown how it is using so much memory.  With `filters` being empty, the query will return all of both collections ... in fact it could even be larger if `"product_id"` is an array and/or there exist one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i see, here is the relation between the 2 collection. so item is a unique document referenced by product_id (a string), and it has a one to many relationship with the Price collection. each item would have at least 15000 price document, so like i said it is expected to use a lot of memory. my issue is still that the `allowDiskUse` is not working correctly

Comment: I wonder if there is a hard limit for array sizes, where `allowDiskUse` isn't applicable. IDK.  Perhaps you could include a `pipeline` in `"$lookup"` to limit the number of docs returned.  I'm not sure what exact limit you are hitting.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes, the memory issue was in the lookup, where some items have 20k price documents. but something i figured out is that the plugin i am using is only paginating (applying limit, and skip) on the last document count which made my aggregate initially query all items (80k) and then lookup all the prices (9M) which resulted in the memory issue. and yes it appears there is a limit on the memory usage even if the disk usage is activated, but i can't seem to find it in their docs

Comment: I asked [_With `”allowDiskUse”: true`, is there a memory limit to the `”$lookup”` stage or array size?_](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/with-allowdiskuse-true-is-there-a-limit-to-the-lookup-stage-or-array-size/224375) on MongoDB Developer Community.